# Istio is not responding on port 80

Tags: http, kubernetes, https, istio, hsts

We set up Istio on our cluster recently, and everything was working fine during our testing. We've now gone live with Istio but now our services are not connecting on port 80; HTTPS works, but we need to have HTTP redirect to HTTPS.

Here is our Istio install config:

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  profile: default
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - enabled: true
        k8s:
          env:
            - name: ISTIO_META_ROUTER_MODE
              value: sni-dnat
          hpaSpec:
            maxReplicas: 5
            metrics:
              - resource:
                  name: cpu
                  targetAverageUtilization: 80
                type: Resource
            minReplicas: 1
            scaleTargetRef:
              apiVersion: apps/v1
              kind: Deployment
              name: istio-ingressgateway
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 2000m
              memory: 1024Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
          service:
            type: LoadBalancer
            externalTrafficPolicy: Local
            ports:
              - name: status-port
                port: 15021
                targetPort: 15021
              - name: http2
                port: 80
                targetPort: 8080
              - name: https
                port: 443
                targetPort: 8443
              - name: tls
                port: 15443
                targetPort: 15443
          strategy:
            rollingUpdate:
              maxSurge: 100%
              maxUnavailable: 25%
        name: istio-ingressgateway
```

Comment: What is your istio version? Could you add `kubectl describe` of you ingress gateway? Could you add yamls of your istio gateway with http-https redirect?

Answer (score 0):

How about check `Service` created by your `IstioOperator` CR in `istio-ingressgateway`? You created the `Ingress Gateway` with `LoadBalancer` type service. Then you should configure the LB routing rules for http and https ports you specified in the yaml.

For instance, if your service configured with all ports as follows, then you had better verify if http port is listening or open at your LB layer. In my example, the `LoadBalancer` type is integrated with AWS and the ELB also created with all the ports I specified. It's logically same with other platforms, it's just different about LB configuration is automated or is required to configure it manually.

```
NAME                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                          PORT(S)
loadbalancer-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   172.30.68.12     xxxxxx.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com   15021:30053/TCP,80:31829/TCP,443:32661/TCP,15443:30937/TCP
```

Comment: it seems there is something off with gateway. A new install works with http, but the moment I add https everything goes haywire. Can't even ping cluster local services